# Concentration inequality for subgaussian random vector

Tags: time-series, high-dimensional, probability-inequalities, subgaussianity

If I have a vector $Z $ in $\mathbb R_d $ space and a vector $B$ in $\mathbb R_d$ space, $Z $ having independent Subgaussian coordinates, is $Z^\top B$ a Subgaussian random variable?

I know sub-gaussianity is preserved under addition rule but is it preserved under any form of linear combination of subgaussian random variables?

Also, how can I bound $X_\theta$:

[image]

I tried using Hoeffding inequality but I am not sure if $Z_t^\top\theta $ is subgaussian or not.

Comment: Use any of the characteristic properties listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Gaussian_distribution to demonstrate that $Z^\prime B$ is subgaussian (and conversely when all the components of $B$ are nonzero).